# Map Reduce Tag Counts Scoped By Date And Category

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am still trying to wrap my brain around map reduce. I have a collection of articles, each of which belongs to one category, and each article has a set of keywords. Assuming that the document looks like this:

```
{
  author: "kris",
  category: "mongodb",
  content: "...",
  keywords: [ "keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3" ],
  created_at: "..."
}
```

I want to essentially pull from all documents the keyword counts, in respect to the author, so I end up with something like:

```
{
  author: "kris",
  categories: {
    mongodb: { keyword1: 5, keyword2: 3, keyword3: 1 },
    ruby: { ... },
    python: { ... }
  }
}
```

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Oh, how thrilled I am by your question! This was actually part of my last assignment for my distributed systems class, so its quite fresh in my recently-graduated mind.

For the parsing details, I'd just google Apache's Hadoop tutorial, but I'll give you the general overview.

Basically, this problem requires two Map-Reduce Phases. In the first map, your input should be a list of `<filename, {list of keywords}>` key-value pairs (might have to do a lil preprocessing on your files, but no biggie). For each of these pairs, you output `<keyword, 1>` as the pair to be handed to the reducer (your basically saying every word should be counted once).

In the first reduce pass, the previous key-value pairs will conveniently be condensed so that each keyword has its own pair of the form `<keyword, {1,1,1,1,1,1}>`, with the number of 1s representing the number of times the word appears throughout all of the documents. So you just sum up the 1s and output `<keyword, sum>`.

The final map/reduce phase is just to sort the keywords by their value. Map: `<keyword,sum> -->  <sum,keyword> Reduce: <sum, {keywords}> --> <keyword,sum>`. This exploits the fact that map-reduce sorts by key when passes to the reduce phase.

Now all of the keywords are next to their word count in sorted order!